# PUT method not working (CodeIngiter + Codeigniter rest server)

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I'm using Codeigniter 3.01 and [Codeigniter rest server](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)
I'm having a problems in put method.
When i run `http://codeang.si/api/task/id/2` via put method (check attached picture) and try to `var_dump($data);` i get this "empty" result:

```
array (size=3)
  'task' => boolean false
  'active' => boolean false
  'date_c' => string '2015-10-11 12:10' (length=16)
```

This is my api controller:

```
    <?php
require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');


class Api extends REST_Controller{

    function tasks_get(){
        // respond with information about a task
        $task = $this->tm->get_all();
        if($task){
            $this->response($task, 200);
        }else{
            $this->response(NULL, 404);
        }
    }

    function task_get(){
        // respond with information about a task
        if(!$this->get('id')){
            $this->response(NULL, 400);
        }
        $task = $this->tm->get($this->get('id'));
        if($task){
            $this->response($task, 200);
        }else{
            $this->response(NULL, 404);
        }
    }

    function task_post(){
        // create task
        $data = array(
            'task' => $this->post('task'),
            'active' => $this->post('active'),
            'date_c' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s")
        );
        $result = $this->tm->create( $data);
        if($result === FALSE){
            $this->response(array('status' => 'failed'));
        }else{
            $this->response(array('status' => 'success'));
        }
    }

    function task_put(){
        // update task
        $id = $this->get('id');
        $data = array(
            'task' => $this->put('task'),
            'active' => $this->put('active'),
            'date_u' => date("Y-m-d h:i:s")
        );
        var_dump($data, $id);
        die();
        $result = $this->tm->update($this->get('id'), $data);
        if($result === FALSE){
            $this->response(array('status' => 'failed'));
        }else{
            $this->response(array('status' => 'success'));
        }
    }

    function task_delete(){
        //delete a task and respond with a status/errors
        $result = $this->tm->delete($this->get('id'));
        if($result === FALSE){
            $this->response(array('status' => 'failed'));
        }else{
            $this->response(array('status' => 'success'));
        }
    }

}
```

And this is my request with result:
[image: Result]

I hope someone can help.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. It's not problem in code, but in my "body".
I had to switch from form-data to x-www-form-urlencoded in Postman chrome extension and now put method works fine.

Here is sample picture:
[image]

Comment: how about if we want to upload file ? is it possible with `x-www-urlencode` ?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be `'task' => $this->input->post('task')` and so on (you were missing the input).

Comment: sorry, but not true. i'm using Codeigniter rest server, so this way should do it. i have switched from form-data to x-www-form-urlencoded in postman and it's working now. Thx any way for your help